# Limit JScrollPane to only show part of its content

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a JScrollPane that contains a JPanel of size 5000x5000 pixels. I want to limit the JScrollPane to only be able to show a subpart of this JPanel.

For example the rectangle defined by the two points (X,Y):

- (500,500) (upper left corner)
- (3000,3000) (lower right corner).

I have tried

```
 myJScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMinimum(500);
```

and

```
myJScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMaximum(3000);
```

But it doesn't work. The setMinimum function only sets the position of the viewport on the scrollpane, setMaximum doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `JPanel` instead to have size (2500, 2500) and render desired fragment of the image. Use `translate()` of the `Graphics` in `paintComponent()` for this.

Comment: The thing is I am useing the JPanel as coordinate space to zoom in on an geometric object made of JLabels. I want to restrict the scrollbars so only the space containing the object is visible. I want to keep the coordinates of the object.